# Mathematical operations in heterogeneous arrays (Matlab)

Tags: matlab, oop

I created a heterogeneous object array in Matlab derived from the `matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous` class. My array now contains objects of the superclass `Cells` and subclasses like `Neuron`, `Astrocyte` etc.
The methods I want to assign to my subclasses are supposed to simulate their behavior depending on different stimuli. In order to calculate the behavior, I need the objects to perform mathematical operations. But when I define a function that uses operators in the methods of the class, Matlab tells me e.g.:

> Undefined operator '-' for input arguments of type 'Cells'.

Then I tried to construct my superclass with multiple inheritances ( `Cells < matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous & double` ), but then this error appears:

> Error using Cells:
> Class 'Cells' cannot be a subclass of
> matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous and also inherit a 'subsasgn' method from
> class 'double'.

which is not surprising, as it says in the description of 'matlab.mixin.Heterogeneous'

> You cannot override the following methods in your subclasses:
>
> ...
>
> subsasgn

As my only other idea would be to define the methods as functions outside the classes, I wanted to ask if there was any possibility to perform mathematical operations in heterogeneous object arrays.

Comment: You need to define the operators for your class. `minus` will define `-`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define the arithmetic operators as methods of your classes otherwise they will not be able to operate on your custom class. For example, to support subtraction, you need to overload `minus` for your class

```
methods
    function self = minus(self, other)
        % Loop through the array and apply the - operator to each 
        for k = 1:numel(self)
            self(k).prop1 = self(k).prop1 - other.prop1;
            self(k).prop2 = self(k).prop2 - other.prop2;
        end
    end
end
```

Note that the `minus` method for your hetergeneous array needs to ensure that elements of `self` of different classes are handled appropriately.

A list of all arithmetic operator methods can be found [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/implementing-operators-for-your-class.html)

Comment: When I add this to the methods part of my `Cells` superclass, it says: Conversion to double from Cells is not possible.

Comment: @P.Hornauer Right. This is an example. You have to *somehow* convert your `Cells` class into something that you can do arithmetic with. What is the actual "value" of your `Cells` class and how do you expect `-` to behave?

Comment: Ah sorry, my fault. My `Cells` class consists of properties which are all of the class double, as I want to do calculations with them. So I basically want the operators to behave as they normally do. But i honestly have no idea how to do that.

Comment: @P.Hornauer See the update which may provide a little clearer idea of how to do that

Comment: Sorry, the solution was too simple for me to consider it, but I figured it out eventually. However, I don't really understand why it works to define the class function as the function itself. I really appreciate your help though, thank you!

Comment: @P.Hornauer What do you mean by "define the class function as the function itself"?

Comment: I am not sure, if that was the way you had in mind, but it worked for me. I just defined 
`function y = minus (obj,A,B)
y = A - B;
end`
The object reference was necessary, although it is not used in the function.